# Processing string is not equal to string

Tags: string, processing

I have to work in processing for this project and I want to load strings and floats from a text file. In my SaveLoad() I check if the name of the first index == "Dot" but it comes back false. I wonder why because the print(name); I put in there prints Dot with no space on the beginning or end, so that is exactly the same right?

```
void SaveLoad()
{
    for (TableRow row : table.rows())
  {
  String name = (String) row.getString("name");
  print(name);
    if(name == "Dot")
    {
      print("1");
      treeCreator.treeDots.add(new TreeDot(int(row.getFloat("x")),int(row.getFloat("y")),int(row.getFloat("dotThickness")),int(row.getFloat("lR")),int(row.getFloat("split"))));
    }
    if(name == "BranchDot")
    {

    }
    if(name == "Leaves")
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare `String` using `==`

https://processing.org/reference/String_equals_.html

do:

`if(name.equals("BranchDot"))`